# How do i use a column from table A to query Table B that has 3 columns that is likely to match the column coming from table A

Tags: sql, postgresql

So I have two tables A and B.
Table A look like this

```
| id       | folder         |
| -------- | -------------- |
| 123      | Space          | 
| 124      | Folder         |
| 125      | List           |
| 126      | Space          |
| 127      | Folder         |
| 128      | List           |
```

Table B:

```
| name     | Folder Id      | Space Id  | List Id | hours |
| -------- | -------------- |-----------|---------|-------|
| Joe      | 124            | 123       |125      | 4     |
| Max      | 124            | 126       |128      | 6     |
| Sam      | 127            | 123       |125      | 3     |
| Jane     | 127            | 126       |128      | 2     |
```

I want to use `id` in table A to query table B where `id` matches any of the following columns in table B `Folder Id`, `Space Id` or `List Id` in Postgres SQL and use the hours respectively to the `id` in table A

Comment: If you want the answer for Postgress then WHY have you tagged MySQL????? DOnt SPAM Tags, they are designed to attract the correct audience for your question, not an angry mob

Comment: Wouldn't a simple `WHERE a.id = b.folder_id OR a.id = b.space_id OR a.id = b.list_id` do the trick here?

Comment: @RiggsFolly actually what I am trying to do is to sum the hours in table B where `id` in table A matches any of the ID in table B so I have previously tried using `OR` but I somehow got duplicates.

Comment: Maybe you need to show us the result you want from this query

Comment: @RiggsFolly Thanks for your help using `OR` with what I needed

Answer (score 0):

```
select sum(t.hours), t.id, t.name
(select hours, name, id
from tableB,
tableA
where tableA.id = tableB."Folder Id"
or tableA.id = tableB."List Id"
or tableA.id = tableB."Space Id") as t
GROUP BY (t.id. t.name)
```

The above query gave me the exact result I needed